# How can i set Metricbeat in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, metricbeat

i'm trying to set metricbeat in my project but with poor results. I need an help step for step, someone would be kind enough to help me please?

Comment: That is a very broad question. Follow this link and see where you run into issues. Ask questions from there on by posting your config, and showing us the errors etc so you can solve this step by step. 
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/configuring-howto-metricbeat.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already setup Elastic and Kibana and you're looking to setup Metricbeat.

### The overall setup goes like this

Metricbeat -> Logstash(Optional) -> Elastic -> Kibana

Following are step by step guideline (for Linux)

1. Download Metricbeat from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/metricbeat
2. Untar on your environment using command tar -xvf `<<downloaded file>`
3. open metricbeat.yml file and setup output location either to Elastic or Logstash
4. Start metricbeat

You may also refer detailed guide on Elastic official website https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-installation-configuration.html

*If you're stuck and not able to start metricbeat completely, post your configuration detail for specific answer.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've resolved the issue. I was wrong to insert the output port on elasticsearch. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Excellent! Glad it is resolved